# Formula in R not updating properly in loop

Tags: r, regression, formula, lm

So in the following I do not get the proper formula out as expected

```
f <- dat[,1] ~ 1
for (j in 3:4) {
  f <- update(f, . ~ . + dat[,j] )
}
```

in only outputs `dat[, 1] ~ dat[, j]`, where dat is a dataframe 1000x4.
The output i need is `dat[,1] ~ 1 + dat[,3] + dat[,4]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be :

```
f <- dat[,1] ~ 1
for (j in 3:4) {
  f <- update(f, paste("~ . + dat[,",j,"]",sep="") )
```